# Data gaps in table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a column with  data [1,2,3,5,8,10,13,14] and I like to find the gaps in tables.

Output should look like

```
MIN  MAX GAP
5    8   3
10   13  3
3    5   2 
8    10  2
```

Thanks.

Comment: What about min=3, max=5, gap=1?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes 5-3 = 2 ;)

Comment: Ok, but there is a gap of one (i.e., one missing). I think GAP should better be calculated as `next - previous - 1` and if the result is `0` there is no gap. We have integer numbers, not real numbers.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - as a general rule, you can't argue with problem specifications. Those come from the business side, it is not for the computer/database people to object to what the business wants or needs. If they need to compute the gap as max - min, and are only interested in "real" gaps (difference greater than one), then that is what the developer must solve for.

Comment: But then the naming is wrong. That would be a *difference* or *step* or *increment*, but not a *gap*. There is no gap between 1 and 2, but there is a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `lead()`:

```
select t.col, t.next_col, (t.next_col - t.col) as gap
from (select t.*, lead(col) over (order by col) as next_col
      from t
     ) t
where t.next_col > t.col + 1;
```

Comment: It works as expected.  I have an additional column and I like to group by that column to find the gaps within that group.   That new column will also be there as 4th column in output.

Comment: @aartist - both solutions (Gordon's, using analytic functions, and mine, using match_recognize) have an optional `partition by` clause, which can be used to accommodate your additional request with almost no extra effort. With that said: when you post a question, post ALL your question from the beginning, don't "build it up little by little." Scope creep is one of the most annoying occurrences on a site like this.

Answer (score 2):

You tagged your post as `oracle12` - which means you can use the `match_recognize` clause for a simple and efficient solution. Don't worry if you are not familiar with the code in the `WITH` clause - I use that only to generate the "test data" (it has nothing to do with the answer to your question).

```
with
  dataset ( val ) as (
    select column_value from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,5,8,10,13,14))
  )
-- End of simulated inpus (for testing only, NOT PART OF THE SOLUTION).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select min, max, gap
from   dataset
match_recognize(
  order by    val
  measures    a.val         as min,
              b.val         as max,
              b.val - a.val as gap
  after match skip to next row
  pattern     ( a b )
  define      b as b.val > a.val + 1
);

       MIN        MAX        GAP
---------- ---------- ----------
         3          5          2
         5          8          3
         8         10          2
        10         13          3
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing  match_recognize.